# Maintaining a single binary across Debian distributions

Tags: debian, gcc, c, gtk, x86

We are currently migrating our system from Debian 6 to 8.  The agenda is to try to maintain a single binary across OS platforms (x86 based)

However, I tried running a Debian 8–compiled binary in Debian 6. It resulted in

> symbol lookup error : g_thread_create

I tried the opposite compilation, and a Debian 6–compiled application runs under Debian 8.

The target platforms are *x86* Atom boards.

Debian 8 `ldd` shows:

```
linux-gate.so.1 (0xb76f5000)
libusb-1.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0 (0xb76c7000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb76ab000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xb76a1000)
libUFScanner.so => /usr/lib/libUFScanner.so (0xb751a000)
libUFMatcher.so => /usr/lib/libUFMatcher.so (0xb74f1000)
libjpeg.so.62 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62 (0xb7492000)
libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0xb73b9000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0xb7237000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xb70e5000)
libssl.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0xb7099000)
libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0xb6f41000)
libmorphosdk.so.6 => /usr/lib/libmorphosdk.so.6 (0xb6f1e000)
libMSO100.so.6 => /usr/lib/libMSO100.so.6 (0xb6f0e000)
libMSO_Drv.so.6 => /usr/lib/libMSO_Drv.so.6 (0xb6f06000)
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xb6a0e000)
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xb694d000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0xb6925000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0xb68fc000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0xb68ee000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0xb689c000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0xb6753000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xb66f5000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0xb66ef000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb66ea000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb65c2000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0xb65bf000)
libftd2xx.so => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libftd2xx.so (0xb657c000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb648a000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xb6444000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6427000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb627d000)
libudev.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0xb626a000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb76f8000)
libusb-0.1.so.4 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libusb-0.1.so.4 (0xb6260000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb6243000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0xb621a000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xb61f4000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0xb61ef000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0xb61eb000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0xb61e4000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0xb602e000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0xb6016000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xb5fd3000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xb5f22000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0xb5f16000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0xb5f12000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0xb5eff000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0xb5ef2000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0xb5ee6000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xb5ed1000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xb5ea4000)
libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0xb5e9a000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0xb5de0000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0xb5ddc000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0xb5dd1000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0xb5dc9000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xb5d58000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xb5d53000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xb5d4d000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0xb5d25000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libresolv.so.2 (0xb5d0e000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0xb5cb1000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xb5c87000)
libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0xb5c7e000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0xb5c62000)
```

Debian 6 `ldd` shows:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7757000)
libusb-1.0.so.0 => /lib/libusb-1.0.so.0 (0xb773a000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7721000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xb7717000)
libUFScanner.so => /usr/lib/libUFScanner.so (0xb7590000)
libUFMatcher.so => /usr/lib/libUFMatcher.so (0xb7567000)
libjpeg.so.62 => /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62 (0xb7547000)
libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 (0xb74bb000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2 (0xb7390000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 (0xb7273000)
libssl.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0xb7227000)
libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0xb70cf000)
libmorphosdk.so.6 => /usr/lib/libmorphosdk.so.6 (0xb70ac000)
libMSO100.so.6 => /usr/lib/libMSO100.so.6 (0xb709d000)
libMSO_Drv.so.6 => /usr/lib/libMSO_Drv.so.6 (0xb7094000)
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xb6d09000)
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xb6c82000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0xb6c66000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0xb6c4d000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0xb6c41000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0xb6bfd000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/libcairo.so.2 (0xb6b88000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xb6b4a000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0xb6b46000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb6b41000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb6a78000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0xb6a73000)
libftd2xx.so => /usr/lib/libftd2xx.so (0xb6a31000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb693b000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xb6915000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb68f7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb67b0000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb775a000)
libusb-0.1.so.4 => /lib/libusb-0.1.so.4 (0xb67a8000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0xb6793000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1 (0xb677a000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXcomposite.so.1 (0xb6777000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXdamage.so.1 (0xb6774000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/libXfixes.so.3 (0xb676f000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xb673f000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXext.so.6 (0xb6730000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1 (0xb6727000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXinerama.so.1 (0xb6724000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXi.so.6 (0xb6716000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/libXrandr.so.2 (0xb670e000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXcursor.so.1 (0xb6705000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0xb6669000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0xb6643000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0xb65cb000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpixman-1.so.0 (0xb6572000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/libpng12.so.0 (0xb654d000)
libxcb-render-util.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-render-util.so.0 (0xb6549000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-render.so.0 (0xb6542000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/libpcre.so.3 (0xb650f000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXau.so.6 (0xb650c000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xb6506000)
libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib/libexpat.so.1 (0xb64e0000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i686/cmov/libresolv.so.2 (0xb64cc000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0xb64b1000)
```

Comment: You'll have to give more information about your binaries if you want any concrete feedback. What does `ldd yourbinary` give on the two different platforms? For maximum portability you probably want to statically link everything as far as possible.

Comment: Paste all information directly into the question. And add the command you are running at the beginning of each output block. And there seems to be far more output that one would expect. Are you just running `ldd` or something else? If that's the output with `-v` then don't give the output with `-v` for now.

Comment: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Deprecated-Thread-APIs.html

Comment: Just `ldd`, not `ldd -v`, for both platforms. And label the output clearly with the platform, please.

Comment: Updated ldd information.

Comment: Are you trying to make one machine a netboot server and nfs server for one binary across multiple machines, or are you simply trying to ensure that all of the binarys installed are all the same image?

Comment: I am trying for  one binary across multiple machines (X86 based)

Comment: Since building on Debian 6 works for you (producing binaries that work on 6 and 8), is that not an acceptable solution?

Comment: @StephenKitt : It would be better if the dev setup is under DEB 8. It will b e easy for future migrations..

Comment: OK. Are you looking to maintain a single *binary* (as your question indicates), or a single *package*?

Comment: @Stephenkitt binary is in my mind. However, I am not able to differentiate what is single package here.

Comment: with a single binary, you try to run the exact same binary on multiple versions of the same distro - this usually involves static linking so there is minimal or no dependence on shared libraries.  single package means re-compiling the binary package for each version of the distro, so each version of the package works with the shared library versions that it was compiled for.  The latter allows your binary to benefit from bug-fixes (incl. security) fixes in newer library versions.  The former does not.

Comment: also, eventually the statically linked binary will stop working if/when the kernel changes enough that it no longer supports (or has changed the interface to) syscalls that the older versions of the static-linked libraries require.

Comment: @Ragav Note that to notify someone of your comment, you need to prefix their name with a @ in the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has been said in the comments, the only reliable way to build a single binary which will work on different releases of Debian (or any Linux distribution) is to build it statically. This is well-supported on Debian and elsewhere, including with `pkg-config` etc. Static binaries can keep working for decades; the kernel's userspace interface is maintained in a backwards-compatible fashion (sometimes it breaks, but that's considered to be a bug and generally fixed quickly). You will find cases where static binaries stop working, but that's usually either related to `libnss` handling (this is dynamic even in static binaries), or changes in the X server's expectations (this happens to [old Linux games](http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/HOWTO_Running_Old_Loki_Games)), or distribution kernels dropping support for features considered obsolete (*e.g.* the OSS sound interface on Ubuntu kernels).

(Another approach is to ship all your dependent libraries and use `rpath` or a shell script to set things up properly; this is what Steam does, and many non-Steam Linux games do this too, but it's less future-proof than static linking and it's harder to fix when things go wrong.)

Your dynamic binary built on Debian 6 work on Debian 8 because the binary's direct dependencies are still available in *your installation* of Debian 8; this is sheer luck and not something you can rely on. For example, your binary is linked to `libssl.so.0.9.8`; that still works for you in Debian 8, because you still have the old `libssl0.9.8` package around (notice that the link is satisfied by `/usr/lib/i686/cmov/libssl.so.0.9.8`, which doesn't use a multiarch path and presumably comes from an older package). Building on Debian 8 with no old packages you'd end up with a link to `libssl.so.1.0.0` instead, and that isn't available in Debian 6. (This is the situation you'd end up in with a newly-installed Debian 8 system.)

Your Debian 8–built binary doesn't work on Debian 6, and that's perfectly normal: binary compatibility is only ascending, not descending. This means that if you build a binary on Debian 6, and it still finds its libraries on Debian 8, then it should work fine; but a binary linked on Debian 8 can expect symbols in libraries which aren't available on Debian 6, without a change in the libraries' sonames. The error you get concerning `g_thread_create` happens because you built on Debian 8, where `libglib-2.0.so.0` has that symbol, but Debian 6's `libglib-2.0.so.0` doesn't. If you built a package containing your binary, the package's dependencies would identify this correctly (you'd get a dependency on at least `libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8)`; Debian 6 only has version 2.24.2).

The best way to future-proof your setup is to produce a source package with dependencies which can be satisfied in Debian 6 and 8; then you can easily build correct binary packages for Debian 6, 7, 8, 9... That is somewhat more involved than building a static binary, at least the first few times you do it, but I think it's worth it in the long run if you plan on doing these types of upgrades in the future. Typically you'd use [`pbuilder`](https://tracker.debian.org/pbuilder) for this, it supports [building for various distributions](https://wiki.debian.org/PbuilderTricks#How_to_build_for_different_distributions) ([`sbuild`](https://wiki.debian.org/PbuilderTricks#How_to_build_for_different_distributions) can also do this). Extending the instructions I linked there for Debian 6 should be relatively easy (duplicate the `STABLE_CODENAME` handling for `OLDOLDSTABLE_CODENAME`, and use the [archive repositories](http://archive.debian.org/)).

Comment: "Building on Debian 8 you'd end up with a link to libssl.so.1.0.0 instead" But The ldd info under debian 8  is mapped with  libssl.so.0.9.8.

Comment: Oh, I thought the `ldd` info was for the single Debian 6–built binary on both platforms. If you built on Debian 8 and the binary is linked to `libssl0.9.8`, that means you have an old `libssl-dev` around; what does `ls -l /usr/lib{,i386-linux-gnu}/libssl*so` produce?

Comment: @Ragav Yes, I asked for the `ldd info` for a single binary on both platforms. Is that not what you listed?

Comment: @StephenKitt I looked at the pbuilder support page for building on different distributions. But how does one handle possible different build and runtime dependency requirements on different distributions/releases? That is not clear to me.

Comment: @FaheemMitha this only works easily if your build dependencies are the same on all your targets (so you build on the older one and make sure the build dependencies are still there on the newer one). If that's not the case, you can sometimes use alternative build dependencies. Runtime dependencies are easier; the build infrastructure (`dpkg-shlibdeps`) will work things out correctly most of the time, and when that fails you can use substitution variables.

Comment: @FaheemMitha you do still need to change the changelog for your targets (with different version numbers) if you want to store the resulting binary packages in the same pool. See [the instructions for backports](http://backports.debian.org/Contribute/) for details; that's why you see versions with `~deb70+1` and the like.

Comment: @FaheemMitha : Binary was built with Deb 8 & LDD listed for built binary under Debian 6 & 8 ...Do you want separate info??

Comment: @StephenKitt :: Yes build was built on Deb 8. ls info for libssl resulted with  "/usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8"

Comment: @Ragav OK, so you have an old `libssl-dev` on your Debian 8 system. The whole `libssl` thing is just an example though, the point I'm making remains. I've also added an explanation for the error you get going the other way.

Comment: @Ragav No, "Binary was built with Deb 8 & LDD listed for built binary under Debian 6 & 8" is fine, if that is the binary you want to run, but please do make that clear in your question. Currently it isn't. Don't expect people to look in comments for information that ought to be in the question.